# How to put together two filled area plots?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I have two data frames:

```
dput(df1)

structure(list(month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), max_wt_per_month = c(145.433333333333, 103, 111.916666666667, 
190.85, 154.683333333333, 136.066666666667, 168.533333333333, 
94.2666666666667, 180, 146.233333333333, 157.4, 179.933333333333
), min_wt_per_month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.05
), avg_wt_per_month = c(8.62182932965783, 8.6232935986297, 10.0719732082026, 
10.0015567184692, 14.7826000421388, 12.4903419254567, 15.2629113635624, 
15.2463245173283, 14.1524047780697, 7.89863122852994, 6.61470640814081, 
8.39703918722787)), .Names = c("month", "max_wt_per_month", "min_wt_per_month", 
"avg_wt_per_month"), row.names = c(5L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
dput(df2)

structure(list(month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), max_wt_per_month = c(113.2, 96.3833333333333, 109.433333333333, 
176.933333333333, 151.333333333333, 122.233333333333, 174.583333333333, 
96.65, 192.05, 164.483333333333, 170.966666666667, 192.883333333333
), min_wt_per_month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    avg_wt_per_month = c(17.6627541466025, 16.6349269588313, 
    21.1785870516185, 20.4826873385013, 26.466982862202, 21.9996887643946, 
    28.8988648947951, 31.9911411411411, 30.0452008346375, 17.4505074160812, 
    17.3421645263354, 21.4158029053789)), .Names = c("month", 
"max_wt_per_month", "min_wt_per_month", "avg_wt_per_month"), row.names = c(5L, 
4L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a filled area plot as shown [here](https://plot.ly/r/filled-area-plots/) (the one is called "Interior Filling for Area Chart"). I can plot `df1` and `df2` separately, however I cannot put them together on a single plot. How to do it?

This is my current code:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(df1, x = ~month, y = ~max_wt_per_month, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'rgba(0,100,80,1)'),
        showlegend = FALSE, name = 'Max, 1') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~min_wt_per_month, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', line = list(color = 'rgba(0,100,80,1)'),
            showlegend = FALSE, name = 'Min, 1') %>%

  plot_ly(df2, x = ~month, y = ~max_wt_per_month, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
          line = list(color = 'rgba(168, 216, 234, 1)'),
          showlegend = FALSE, name = 'Max, 2') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~min_wt_per_month, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(168, 216, 234, 1)', line = list(color = 'rgba(168, 216, 234, 1)'),
            showlegend = FALSE, name = 'Min, 2') %>%

  layout(title = "...",
         paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
         xaxis = list(title = "months",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "wt",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE))
```

It gives me an error:

`Error: First argument,`data`, must be a data frame.`

I checked that `class(df1)` and `class(df2)` return `data.frame`. So, don't really understand this message.

The expected result is something similar to [this one](https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/).

**Update 1:**

I tried to use `ggplot2` with the following modifications in the data structure (but in this case the chart looks like a bar chart (with very thin bars), not filled area chart):

```
df1$type = "1"
df2$type = "2"

data_merged = rbind(df1,df2)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_merged, aes(x=month, y=max_wt_per_month, fill=as.factor(type))) +
+ geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.4) +
+     scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens", breaks=rev(levels(as.factor(data_merged$type))))
```

**Update 2:**

I have just realized that `ggplot2` works if I substitute month names with numbers, but how can I mantain month names??

Comment: I think the error here is pretty self explanatory, you trying to "pipe" your first plot into your second. You are passing a class "plotly_hash" to the second plot.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: Do you have any idea about the solution to this problem?

Comment: Simply replace your second `plot_ly()` call by `add_trace()` and specify `... data = df2` (same with the last `add_trace()`)

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: Ok, it works now, but I see only one filled area chart. Maybe `ggplot2` would be more suitable for this case? The only issue that I have with `ggplot2` is that months must be numeric to show filled area chart. But I want them to be month names.

Comment: It works fine on my end. I'm using  `plotly v4.5.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to "pipe" your first plot into your second one (so basically trying to pass a class `plotly_hash` instead of a `data.frame`). Simply replace your second `plot_ly()` call by `add_trace()` and specify `data = df2`. You also need to specify `x = ~month` in your `add_trace()`s calls.
Here's a simpler representation:

```
plot_ly(df1, 
        x = ~month, 
        y = ~max_wt_per_month, 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'rgba(0,100,80,1)'),
        showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~month,
            y = ~min_wt_per_month, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty',
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~month, 
            y = ~max_wt_per_month, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines',
            showlegend = FALSE, 
            data = df2) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~month,
            y = ~min_wt_per_month, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', 
            showlegend = FALSE, 
            data = df2)
```

---

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to add some transparency to the filled areas so that the right side of the green chart would be visible. Now it is overlaped with the blue one.